# Unique copy of vector<unique_ptr>

Tags: c++, vector, copy, unique-ptr

I have a class object which contains a `vector<unique_ptr>`. I want a copy of this object to run non-const functions on. The original copy must remain **const**.

What would the copy constructor for such a class look like?

```
class Foo{
public:
 Foo(const Foo& other): ??? {}

 std::vector<std::unique_ptr> ptrs;
};
```

Comment: "Unique" here does not mean "extraordinary".

Comment: @molbdnilo Surely you can copy the data pointed to by a unique_ptr. `data = *ptr;`

Comment: Unique means just the one. Copying something unique is a contradiction in terms. I suspect you need `std::shared_ptr` if you want copies.

Comment: @WillyGoat yes, but that's not what you're trying to accomplish. That would leave you with two distinct but identical things. You're trying to create two vectors that both contain the same unique things, which is like putting one egg in two baskets.

Comment: @molbdnilo: How do you know what he's trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You cannot simply copy a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr>` because `std::unique_ptr` is not copyable so it will delete the vector copy constructor.

If you do not change the type stored in the vector then you could make a "copy" by creating a whole new vector like

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<some_type>> from; // this has the data to copy
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<some_type>> to;
to.reserve(from.size()) // preallocate the space we need so push_back doesn't have to

for (const auto& e : from)
    to.push_back(std::make_unique<some_type>(*e));
```

Now `to` is a separate copy of `from` and can be changed independently.

---

Additionally: If your type is polymorphic the above won't work as you would have a pointer to the base class.  What you would have to do is make a virtual `clone` member function and have `clone` return a `std::unique_ptr` to a copy of the actual derived object.  That would make the code look like:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<some_type>> from; // this has the data to copy
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<some_type>> to;
to.reserve(from.size()) // preallocate the space we need so push_back doesn't have to

for (const auto& e : from)
    to.push_back(e->clone());
```

Comment: This is what I want. Thank you

Comment: @brian Thanks for catching the missing reference

Comment: What happens when the vectors are destroyed, and all the unique_ptrs try to delete the objects they point to?

Comment: @BoPersson It is a separate instance so the original vector would be left unchanged.

Comment: @NathanOliver Instead of clone function can we call the right copy constructor using switch on `typeid(some_type)` ?

Comment: @MatthieuH It's possible.  It's a design flaw normally though.

Comment: @NathanOliver So clone function is a best practice ?

Comment: @m Yes.  Otherwise you have a "maintenance point".  i.e., if you add more derived types you need to visit this spot and add more if statements.  If you use virtual functions, it just works.

Comment: @NathanOliver And can we use dynamic_cast to call the right copy constructor?

Comment: @MatthieuH You can, but again you are in the same place where you manually have to code all copy operation paths like you would with `typeid`.  `typeid` and `dynamic_cast` are both going to have a run time hit so why not just go all out and use a virtual function?

Comment: @NathanOliver Ok, I will do that but I searched a other solution because my class is complexe and I use default copy constructor. There I have to reimplement copy and if I forget a variable the copy will be wrong.

Comment: @MatthieuH The `clone` method will use your default copy constructor.  The whole function would just be something like `Derived * clone() { return new Derived(*this); }`. There is nothing to mess up with that.

Comment: @NathanOliver Oh ! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Nathan's answer above is great. Additionally in the the polymorphic case, I found [this site](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2018/11/06/how-to-transfer-unique_ptrs-from-a-set-to-another/) useful for defining the clone() member function.

I used

```
std::unique_ptr<Base> Base::clone()
{
  return std::make_unique<Derived>(*this);
}
```

which is similar to Nathan's later comment.

Comment: I believe you can make this easily copy-pastable with `return std::make_unique<std::decay_t<decltype(*this)>>(*this);`. C++23's deduced `this` might even allow you to define the whole thing in the base class as a template function!