# Deep copy with unique_ptr in map

Tags: c++

I would like to create a deep copy of a class that contains a `unique_ptr`.

How can this be achieved?

I have the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

class test;

typedef std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> sMap;
typedef std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<test>> testMap;

class test {
    public:
    sMap     map1;
    testMap  map2; 

    test(){}

    // test(const test& t)
    // : 
    // map1(t.map1),
    // map2(t.map2) ??
    // {}
};

int main() {
    sMap myMap; 
    myMap["a"] = "b";

    std::unique_ptr<test> tobj= std::make_unique<test>();
    test& obj = *tobj;
    obj.map1 = myMap;

    test obj2;
    obj2.map2.emplace("one", std::move(tobj));

    // test obj3 (obj2); // error
    return 0;
}
```

How can I copy the data in the `map2` when calling the copy constructor?

Kind regards

Comment: What is the copy supposed to do with the unique_ptrs?

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34797849/unique-copy-of-vectorunique-ptr

Comment: seems a little bit off then having a unique_ptr in the class, better with a shared_ptr

Comment: I was not able to compile the code with `std::unordered_map<std::string, test>`. So I tried it with smart pointers and it worked. But I needed a way to copy the objects when the copy constructor or assignment operator got called

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to copy the instances that the `unique_ptr`s point at, you need to do so manually because `unique_ptr`s are non-copyable. No two `unique_ptr`s should ever point at the same instance!

Example:

```cpp
class test {
public:
    sMap     map1;
    testMap  map2; 

    test() = default;

    test(const test& other) : map1(other.map1) { // copy constructor
        for(auto&[str, ptr] : other.map2) {
            if(ptr) // recursively copy construct:
                map2.emplace(str, std::make_unique<test>(*ptr));
            else // empty pointer, put `nullptr` in there:
                map2.emplace(str, nullptr);
        }
    }

    test(test&& other) noexcept = default;      // move constructor

    test& operator=(const test& other) {        // copy assignment
        // copy construct an instance and move assign it:
        *this = test(other);
        return *this;
    }

    test& operator=(test&& other) noexcept = default; // move assignment
};
```

Comment: Small sidenote: In case there are classes that inherit from `test` within that map than this will result in [object slicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing) (in that case something like a virtual `clone()` method would be needed, e.g. [like in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43263477/8411406)) - if on the other hand there are no potential subclasses of test then the map could be implemented without `unique_ptr`'s (i.e. `std::unordered_map<std::string, test>`), which would make `test` copyable by default.

Comment: That strategy seems good. I would have to create a pure virtual function on `test` and than write a `clone` function. Thats it? but that way I will not be able to create `test` objects

Comment: I will try to make it and post it here

Comment: @Trailer If you _do_ use `unique_ptr` because of polymorphism and not one of the other reasons one may use it, adding a `virtual clone()` member is the idiomatic way to do it as Turlefight mentioned. Here's one way to start: [example](https://godbolt.org/z/z8G8b3W3T). I haven't tested it or put too much thought into it though, so take it with a grain of salt.

Comment: How can you copy a link  from that web site? Edit: Got it!!  I tried the implementation on the post. https://godbolt.org/z/nMfTa1jza but it won't compile :/

Comment: @Trailer With that approach, you need to change your `typedef`s: [example](https://godbolt.org/z/ffoTqcsWx) (see the `testMap` change I made)

Comment: @TedLyngmo, Sorry to bother you again with this topic. I tried this example https://godbolt.org/z/ErM3378r5. It compiles and seems to work. Would you be so kind as to verify the implementation?

Comment: @Trailer I'd add all 5 of the "big 5" in the base class lsince it is polymorphic ([example](https://godbolt.org/z/Y1e4M68rv)) but other than that, it looks ok. Note that for code reviews, there's a better site: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/